# Angular Library is not running ngOnInit when used

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I'm following the Angular CLI 6 instructions for creating a library [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library). I was able to make my library, and build it successfully. The library consists of a `Component` I am using for the UI and has an HTML `selector`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-lib',
  templateUrl: './my-lib.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-lib.component.css'],
  providers: [MyService],
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string;

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService) {
    console.log("constructor");    
  }

  ngOnInit {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
    this.myService.DoStuff();
  }
}
```

Now I have a separate project I am trying to use this library in. I'm not publishing it yet, so I am using it by copying the contents of `dist/<my-lib>` into the `node_modules` of the other project. I was using `npm link` before, but I hit the issue described [here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library/issues/277), and this solution worked for me.

I can successfully import the library and `Module` and use the `Component` in the HTML file with its selector, along with passing inputs: `<my-lib [id]="'my-id'">`. The `id` is passed down correctly, but the logic in the `ngOnInit` that is not getting run. The console does NOT print `"ngOnInit"`. But it DOES print `"constructor"`, and the Component UI elements show up correctly.

Am I missing something to get the `ngOnInit` logic to run?

EDIT: I should mention that the library is running:

- `"@angular/core": "^6.0.3"`
- `"@angular/cli": "~6.0.7"`

and the project I'm trying to use the library in is:

- `"@angular/core": "^5.0.1"`
- `"@angular/cli": "^1.6.5"`

Not sure if this will affect anything or not.

EDIT2: Fix example code.

Comment: if you are using gulp then it remove console.log when you are build project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only issue i see is that your instance of the service also has the same name, change it as

```
constructor(
    private apiService: myService) {
    console.log("constructor");    
  }

ngOnInit {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
    this.apiService.DoStuff();
  }
```

also hope that you have imported,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

also remove providers in component and move it to the module level.

Comment: Whoops, should be `private myService: MyService`. And yes, I am importing those! The UI from the Component renders correctly, so it builds fine. It's just the logic in ngOnInit is not run.

Comment: try removing providers from the component and move it to the module level

Comment: why the answer is removed?

Comment: Sorry! I thought I had jumped the gun, since something wasn't working, but it was unrelated to this. Moving the Service to the Module provider worked to allow my service to work! :) Thanks!